# What is the preferred way to handle data in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have ~30 lists, some dictionaries and most of these contain 200 items at least, integers and strings.

The data is scraped using selenium and beautiful soup to parse the html, then that is separated into names/values lists, site refreshes and the process repeats.

While that is happening I'm executing functions to process those names/values into averages, rates of change over time, then comparing those to prior results.

At the moment it's all just being stored in memory inside my python script. I've looked at using csv files to store and retrieve the data, or an sqlite database/ or even using sqlite database in memory but don't know how much faster/slower those options are.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: The solution to use depends on constraints that you've not specified in your question and on the specific details of how the data stored is meant to be used later. As written, your question is primarily opinion-based. Can you use CSV? Yes. A SQL database? Yes. Pickles? Yes. A JSON dump? Yes.

Comment: The data is being consumed basically as soon as it's being captured, I said that I think? I was just worried about the upper limits of memory storage and whether I should be doing something else, or rather at what point will my computer not be able to cope with that much data in memory!

Comment: From my comment "**specific** details". Saying "The data is being consumed basically as soon as it's being captured" is not specific at all.

Comment: Okay – every 10 seconds a new list of prices is captured, that is processed and so forth, relative to the previous 10 seconds worth of data, after a minute it repeats and those original 6 x 10 sec captures are overridden with new values. Next to no data is retained longer than say ~5 mins at a time

Answer (score 1):

You say that your data is mostly `Lists` and `Dicts` then my choice would be to use `JSON`.

JSON is perfect for `key-value` pairs, it was originally made for this purpose.

JSON is very easy to serialize or decode using the `json` module.

Example of serializing JSON

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
['foo', {'bar': ['baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
```

Example of encoding `list` and `dict` to JSON

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], separators=(',', ':'))
'[1,2,3,{"4":5,"6":7}]'
```

More documentation is available at:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html